# Unable to achieve 120Hz on U22.04, stuck at 60Hz

Tags: dual-boot, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I came across a problem with being unable to get 120Hz on my main monitor(dual setup, second monitor is 75Hz and works fine). I've tried multiple "xrandr" commands, searching on  similar posts, but I'm still stuck.

My main monitor is ASUS ROG P278Q, 144Hz on DisplayPort-1 but due to cable it only gets me to 120Hz(works fine on windows 10, I use ubuntu as dual boot). Upon fresh installing 22.04 version I can't get it to work on 120Hz.

Upon writing `cvt -v -r 2560 1440 120` I get the following

```
Warning: Refresh Rate 120.00 is not CVT standard (50, 60, 75 or 85Hz).
# 2560x1440 119.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 182.81 kHz; pclk: 497.25 MHz Modeline "2560x1440R" 497.25  2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1448 1525 +hsync -vsync
```

Even if I try to achieve 85Hz it won't work, monitor goes black screen.
I use AMD graphics card.

Any help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After 3 days of messing with this, I finally found a modeline thanks to the https://tomverbeure.github.io/video_timings_calculator

```
    Modeline "2560x1440_120" 497.75 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1525 +HSync -VSync
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this is literally the same as the one in your question